# List<dynamic>.Find and List<dynamic>.FindAll

Tags: dynamic, lambda

I am trying to do this but unable to find a workaround.

I have a list of dynamic objects and its like `ObjectList : List<dynamic>`

its filled with objects that have a dynamic property `LastName`.

i am trying to find all elements that have a matching string in the Name property.

```
var result = mylist.FindAll(e => e.LastName.StartsWith("Mc"));
```

But when i do so, it says *"Expression cannot contain lambda expressions"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use it like lambda if it dynamic try using it in different style

```
var result = mylist.FindAll(e => e.LastName.StartsWith("Mc"));
```

something like this should help

```
var result=(from c in mylist where c.LastName.StartsWith("Mc") select c).ToList();
```

Comment: I just tried your way and still it throws the same error. Whats next?